# Ubuntu 12.04 Second monitor stopped working after updates and restart

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, multiple-monitors

I use Ubuntu 12.04 in a dual boot setup on a HP machine. My second monitor suddenly stopped working after I installed updates and restarted my machine. I actually had it set up with three monitors but I recently removed the cable to the third monitor. The funny thing is that when I go to System Settings -> Displays, I can see that it detects both monitors. Not sure what to do

My video chip is Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770 GHz Edition]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. You may be able to get help on a different [se] site such as [ubuntu.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something changed in FGLRX driver.
Have you tried to go in

```
system settings > hardware > additional drivers
```

and deactive the proprietary driver?

Maybe with the default opensource driver you could have a bit of luck